# Flutter Firebase authentication: can userChanges / idTokenChanges revert to generating a null user, from an external event?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Before signing in, `userChanges` / `idTokenChanges` produces a null user, signifying that the user is not signed in. When the user signs in, the stream produces a valid `User` instance.

Is there any way that, based on an external event (i.e. not something the user did within the app), e.g. the user's access token being revoked, the stream can go back to producing a null user, effectively signalling that Firebase has signed the user out? Or would events like that instead be reflected in the ID token changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase manages the user's authentication session and checks whether the user is still signed in at least once an hour. At this point it is indeed possible for the `userChanged` stream to get a `null` again.

There are multiple ways the user can revert to being signed-out, but a simple one to test with is **disabling the user account** in the Firebase console.

Comment: Great, I'll test by doing that. Thanks.